# Macbook Pro suddenly lagging video playback + Flash sites

Tags: mac, video, vlc-media-player, flash-player

I have a Macbook Pro, OSx Lion, Intel Core2 Duo, 4GB Ram, NVidia Geforce 8600M GT 128 MB Ram, Intel x25m SSD. Approximately 4 years old.

I've been running Flash sites and playing videos without any problems for years. Then suddenly 3 months ago, a flash site like http://thefwa.com is lagging in all browsers. Even mouseover animations - anything.

Also video playback in e.g VLC and Quicktime is now lagging. Same videos I used before, I tried installing an older version of VLC without any luck.

Playing back video in VLC utilizes the CPU almost 100%, and Flash sites like thefwa.com easily takes up 50-60%.

It's as if the hardware acceleration stopped working, or the GPU lost its magic.

**UPDATE: Same issues also occurred on Snow Leopard**

Has anyone experienced something similar, or do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: You had these issues in snow leopard too?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the SSD. The non-G2 models on x25m didn't have very good TRIM support. Try this bootable ISO to diagnose: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18363

Comment: this is the G2 model. Also, since I just re-formatted the disk should be 'trimmed', or?

Comment: My suggestion still stands. If you reformatted the drive and the issue is persistent after upgrading to the new OS there can only be two possibilities. 1) Hardware issue - the SSD, and less likely but still possible, 2) you're installing software after the upgrade that is causing the issue and you should flush the OS and gradually add back programs to try and cause the issue (Like browser extensions.)